# Angularjs filter always returns true

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-filter

I've made filter for ng-repaet that looks like this:

```
  $scope.filterRoutine = function(col) {
        return _.isEqual(col.Routine.IsIndoor, true);
}
```

It works fine (isEqual returns true or false).

But this doesn't work, and I don't know why is that (when I say it doesn't work, I don't get any errors, but view doesn't change)

```
 $scope.filterRoutine = function(col) {
         return _.forEach(tempData, function (temp) {
                    if (_.find(col.Exercises, { Exercise: temp })) {
                        return true;                          
                    } else {
                        return false;
                    }
            });
}
```

What I do here (or rather what I want to do) is this: I have tempData collection, if my col.Exercises has at least one item from tempData it should be showed in the view. 
But for some reason all items are showed in the view i.e. nothing has been filtered.

My guess is that this because this function always returns true (because always at least one col.Exercises should contain item from tempData).

How can I fix this i.e. hide all cols which don't contain any items from tempData ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Returning from [_.forEach](http://lodash.com/docs#forEach) does not do what you expect it to do.
You'll need to do something like this:

```
$scope.filterRoutine = function(col) {
     var x = false;

     _.forEach(tempData, function (temp) {
                if (_.find(col.Exercises, { Exercise: temp })) {
                    x = true;                          
                }
        });

     return x

}
```

Also, "Callbacks may exit iteration early by explicitly returning false.", meaning your `return false` was stoping iteration after the first time `_.find` returned `false`.